# URL cannot be resolved to a type in appium

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

What is this error?
I used this code but it is not running

```java
package AppiumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class myAppiumTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    AndroidDriver dr;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    public void call() {

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName","Honor 6x");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.youdao.hindict");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.youdao.hindict.activity.LockScreenActivity");

        dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), "caps");
    }
}
```

**ERROR :** 
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
FAILED: call
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    URL cannot be resolved to a type

```
at AppiumTest.myAppiumTest.call(myAppiumTest.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
Default suite

## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: `import java.net.URL;` and I recommend that you remove the suppress warnings options and deal with the warnings.  They are likely related.  For example, your `AndroidDriver dr;` should probably be `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> dr;`

Comment: Not Helping @Bill Hileman
Tried both things but same issue

Comment: Not Helping @Bill Hileman
Tried both things but same issue

The constructor AndroidDriver<WebElement>(URL, String) is undefined

Comment: Adding the import should have fixed the URL error.  You'd also need another import when you reference AndroidElement but it should automatically recommend the correct import.  You'd also need to add the <AndroidElement> on the initialization line, but you're saying we're still not past the URL error message?

Comment: `dr = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"), caps);` notice the caps should NOT have quotes.

Comment: [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
FAILED: call
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'GAURAV', ip: '192.168.162.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

Comment: At this point, I suggest you create a new post since the error you're now getting is entirely different from your original scenario.  I helped get you this far, but I prefer not to do all the hand-holding and debugging for you.  Perhaps others will take it from here.  Post your new, updated code in the new post complete with error message.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you help me with TeamViewer session in this issue @Bill